# kurtosis function show different values in python and matlab

Tags: python, matlab, kurtosis

Python 3.5
MATLAB 2013b

I have a simple array.

**MATLAB:**

```
x = [1,2,3,4,5];
kurtosis(x)
```

> 1.7

**Python:**

```
def mykurtosis(x):
    return scipy.stats.kurtosis(x)

x = [1,2,3,4,5]
print(mykurtosis(x))
```

> -1.3

Why it shows different outputs ?

Is it the right way to define in Python ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're using `Fisher's definition`, you intend to use `Pearson’s definition` of kurtosis:

```
IN: scipy.stats.kurtosis([1,2,3,4,5], axis=0, fisher=False)
OUT: 1.7
```

Comment: thank you, what is the actual difference in both of these ? Any links to study about the difference, Wiki has mentions about pearson only. In that case can we change like that in Matlab as well ?